# Wine apps crashed after update

Tags: wine, winetricks

Today after I logged in, I got a message to update Line. I clicked OK and it seemed to start updating, but after a while, it crashed. I tried to remove Wine and Winetricks, and reinstall them to no avail (after the reinstall it still crashed). How do I fix it or start troubleshooting the problem? Please note that I'm not that familiar with Wine/winetricks or even Linux, so if you can be kind enough to explain step by step, it would be much appreciated.

My system:
  Ubuntu 16.04
  Wine 4.0~Xenial, I added Wine ppa.
  winetricks 0.0+20141009+svn1208-2ubuntu1
  ps: when I ran `winetricks --version`, I got this: `20181203-next` 
  ps: when I ran Line from command line, got this output:

```
0009:fixme:shcore:SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID L"C:\\users\\michael\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\LINE\\bin\\LineLauncher.exe": stub
0009:fixme:toolhelp:CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Unimplemented: heap list snapshot
0009:fixme:toolhelp:CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Unimplemented: heap list snapshot
0009:fixme:toolhelp:CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Unimplemented: heap list snapshot
0009:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33f584 (nil)): stub
002a:fixme:toolhelp:CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Unimplemented: heap list snapshot
0009:fixme:toolhelp:CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Unimplemented: heap list snapshot
0009:fixme:toolhelp:CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Unimplemented: heap list snapshot
002a:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
0009:fixme:toolhelp:CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Unimplemented: heap list snapshot
0009:fixme:toolhelp:CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Unimplemented: heap list snapshot
002a:fixme:msvcp:_Mtx_init_in_situ unknown flags ignored: 2
002a:fixme:msvcp:_Mtx_init_in_situ unknown flags ignored: 2
002a:fixme:msvcp:_Mtx_init_in_situ unknown flags ignored: 2
002a:fixme:msvcp:_Mtx_init_in_situ unknown flags ignored: 2
002a:fixme:msvcp:_Mtx_init_in_situ unknown flags ignored: 2
002a:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x33f008 1 C) semi-stub
002a:fixme:shcore:SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID L"C:\\users\\michael\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\LINE\\bin\\LineLauncher.exe": stub
002a:fixme:file:FindFirstFileExW flags not implemented 0x00000002
002b:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x813febc (nil)): stub
0009:fixme:toolhelp:CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Unimplemented: heap list snapshot
002a:fixme:sync:SetWaitableTimerEx (0x154, 0x33f6bc, 0, (nil), (nil), (nil), 32) semi-stub
002a:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33f284,0x00000000), stub!
002a:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x33f458 1 C) semi-stub
002a:fixme:msvcp:_Mtx_init_in_situ unknown flags ignored: 2
002a:fixme:msvcp:_Mtx_init_in_situ unknown flags ignored: 2
002a:fixme:msvcp:_Mtx_init_in_situ unknown flags ignored: 102
002a:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x3374f8 1 C) semi-stub
002a:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x3372c8 1 C) semi-stub
002a:fixme:msvcp:_Mtx_init_in_situ unknown flags ignored: 2
002a:fixme:msvcp:_Mtx_init_in_situ unknown flags ignored: 2
002a:fixme:msvcp:_Mtx_init_in_situ unknown flags ignored: 102
002a:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x33f108 1 C) semi-stub
002a:fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33f480,0x00000001,0x33f478) stub
002a:fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
0032:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x94ef818 1 C) semi-stub
002a:fixme:toolhelp:CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Unimplemented: heap list snapshot
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to jkfloris from WineHQ for sharing, the problem is solved by running `winetricks vcrun2015`, the original post is [here](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=31909).